# The expression "tenir des propos"

Tags: expressions

> Seul quelqu'un qui n'y connaîtrait rien en politique **tiendrait de tels propos**.

The precise meaning of this expression eludes me. Does it mean:

"**have/hold such opinions**" without expressing them overtly?

Or is it more like:

"**express such opinions / make such remarks**" for others to hear?

Comment: To: @jlliagre When I hear the verb "tenir", it conjures up the image of "holding" something. So it is easy to be swayed into the wrong interpretation "have/hold such opinions". Which makes me wonder -- what is an idiomatic way to express the idea "have/hold such opinions", on the other hand? I mean, without expressing them to others? Merci.

Comment: "**avoir** de tels propos" = just "have/hold such opinions" without expressing them to others?

Comment: *Un/des propos* means something you say, express, tell (often used in plural). So *avoir des propos* means to tell something, as *tenir des propos*. *Avoir des propos* is of course not an idiom. Note that I think you cannot *dire des propos*, *exprimer des propos*, maybe because a *propos* is already something said, expressed.

Comment: LUNA, as it was clearly directed to me, you'd better have put your comment after my reply and not as a comment to your own question. Answer updated.

Comment: Note also that I didn't receive any notification despite your @jlliagre tag. this explains why: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work

Comment: Y is everyone parroting the dictionary? [http://en.bab.la/dictionary/french-english/tenir-des-propos]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latter: *Tenir des propos* is an idiom that means to openly tell something.

It is slightly formal. It is usually followed by an adjective qualifying the expressed statements, e.g.:

*Il tient des propos joyeux/intelligents/incohérents/racistes/injurieux/surprenants/sensés/...*

Here, *de tels propos* means words that would clearly reveal the speaker's lack of knowledge about politics.

While a common meaning for *tenir* is "to hold", it has a much wider range of usage like its latin ancestor *tenēre*, as much as sixty nine [according to wikipedia](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/tenir). See also the [dictionnaire de l'académie](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie8/tenir).

*[Propos](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/propos)* means statements here.